# Set NewRelic app name per-request

Tags: python, django, newrelic

I'd like to break some specific views from a django app out into a separate NewRelic application. The [NewRelic python docs](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/python/python-agent-configuration#per-request-configuration) implies that I can set `request.environ['newrelic.app_name']` and it will use my new value instead of the default one, but it doesn't appear to work.

eg. in my wsgi file:

```
from django.core.handlers.wsgi import WSGIHandler
import newrelic.agent

application = WSGIHandler()
newrelic.agent.initialize('/path/to/newrelic.ini')  # defines app_name='1st_app'
application = newrelic.agent.wsgi_application()(application)
```

in my Django view:

```
def some_view(request, *args, **kwargs):
    request.environ['newrelic.app_name'] = '2nd_app'
    ...
    return HttpResponse(...)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can split these views out in mod_wsgi, but it must be done at the server level and not with Django. Use the SetEnv directive in your Apache config instead. Since you want to change the app_name based on request, you will need to use the Location directive to identify which URL should be re-named.

For example:

```
<Location /some/url>
SetEnv newrelic.app_name 2nd_app
</Location>
```

Comment: So it needs to be done *before* the request gets anywhere near the app server, rather than during processing? #FeatureSuggestion